Why does «приходиться» mean "to have to"?
So, «приходить» means "to come", which etymologically makes sense to me. Why does making this word reflexive, «приходиться», suddenly make it mean "to have to"?

Well, there is no point arguing with idioms. All languages have them and they are what they are. Приходиться literally would mean "to arrive itself" (OK, the "itself" doesn't make sense to an English mind with an intransitive verb), but fundamentally means "to happen to be", even if you shouldn't force that phrase into all translations, or "to have occasion to be".

As someone has pointed out, there is он приходится мне двоюродным братом, "he is (happens to be) my cousin".

Четверть всего экспорта приходится на нефть: we say this the other way round in English -- "oil accounts for a quarter of exports" -- but you can understand it as "a quarter of exports happen to go on oil". [Exports has to be plural in this sentence in English.]

Ему приходилось тяжело: he had a hard time of it (lit. it happened to him to be hard).

Нам приходилось помогать им: we had to help them (lit. it happened to us to help them). "We had occasion to help them" then moves semantically to "we had to help them".


It is much better to simply accept нам приходится это сделать as an idiom, recite that a hundred times in your head - and then you've got it.
You didn't point it out,  but meanings 3 and 4 are not just reflexive, but impersonal. You can compare the English impersonal verb "behove" ("behoove" in some English-speaking countries): "it behoves us to do so", which is an impersonal statement meaning "we ought to do so".
Also: I suppose you already know, but the perfective counterpart of мне приходится is мне придётся. This is obvious in a way, but not that obvious when looked at another way.

I don't think it's helpful to try to force a "happen" translation for most of your examples. For example, Она тебе кем приходится? = What relation is she to you?

I agree, as I said myself in fact, but the original poster specifically wanted something that showed the derivation. I said "you shouldn't force that phrase into all translations".

The word "приходиться" is used to express relationship, for example "Он приходится мне двоюродным братом." The same word also has a very different meaning and expresses necessity to do something, for example "Мне приходится делать домашнее заданее после школы."
